# Where is the URI of a downloaded file stored?

Tags: data-transfer, metadata

If I "Get Info" on an image I downloaded, I see the URI of the original:[image]
Where/how is this stored?  I'd like to come up with a command-line way of getting it from multiple files.

Neither `exiftool` nor `strings filename` shows it.  There is no resource fork, at least not in `._filename` or `filename/rsrc`

XMP shows that this example was created by Archives of Canada, although I did not download it from their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata like this are stored as [extended attributes](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/10/24/theres-more-to-files-than-data-extended-attributes/) of the file itself -- namely, the `kMDItemWhereFroms` key.

You can view it on the CLI via

```
xattr -lp com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms foo.jpg
```

With `exiftool`, you'd need to specify the key to retrieve per [the exiftools documentation](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/MacOS.html)

```
exiftool -XAttrMDItemWhereFroms foo.jpg
```

To retrieve programmatically, you would need to make a `getxattr()` call, such as with the Python [xattr](https://pypi.org/project/xattr/) module.